# How to mark an empty conditional block in Java

Tags: java, coding-standards

In C++ when I wanted to mark that if is empty by design I added `NULL;` as statement:

```
if (cond1) {
    ...
} else if (cond2) {
    NULL;
} else {
    ...
}
```

However in Java it seems to be impossible to have `null;` as statement. What is the correct way of marking empty by design if in Java (is it just comment)?

Comment: If I really want to mark it I use: //do nothing

Comment: What's wrong with using comments?

Comment: Why are you making empty blocks? You could re-write that as `} else if (!cond2) {` and follow that with the contents of the else block.

Comment: unholysampler: In this case yes (I was more interested here to give short sample then anything else) - it was just that the cond2 is longer and there are several ifs after that. I'd need to prepend the condition to each of them.

Comment: Mike Baranczak: Nothing - but I was wondering if there is other idiom to do this.

Comment: @MaciejPiechotka: Or nest the following conditions inside the block.

Comment: @Maciej Piechotka: Then encapsulate the condition in a nice method that returns bool or just evaluate it once and store it in a local variable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Firstly, how is this:

```
if (cond1) {
    ...
} else if (cond2) {
    NULL;
} else {
    ...
}
```

Better than:

```
if (cond1) {
    ...
} else if (cond2) {

} else {
    ...
}
```

The `NULL;`-statement doesn't tell anything, or does it?

Secondly, as others pointed out, you don't have to have that empty block, unless you need to say something about the condition or possibly leave space to handle it.

So this makes perfect sense:

```
if (cond1) {
    ...
} else if (cond2) {
    //cond2 is not handled, because 2 is the smallest prime number
} else {
    ...
}
```

Or this:

```
if (cond1) {
    ...
} else if (cond2) {
    //TODO: investigate whether/how this condition needs to be handled
} else {
    ...
}
```

However an undocumented empty consequence serves no purpose, whether you write `NULL;` in there or not.

Lastly, if you feel like you are having too many conditions, then you should investigate how behavioral patterns and polymorphism in general could help you clean up your code.

Comment: I presume the point of the `NULL` is to make clear that the programmer *intended* an empty block, rather than a line having been deleted by mistake or the like. However, in that case a comment would work as well.

Answer (score 11):

That's a bad practice altogether and you shouldn't have this block in the first place. If you don't react on a condition then don't code it. It's a code smell and contains hardly any useful information. Using it to design a program flow is even worse, as this can always be expressed more elegantly.

The correct way of handling this is to remove the unecessary `else if` or to rewrite your conditions instead of having a marker for an empty block.

In your example that would be:

```
if (cond1) 
{
    ...
}
else if(!cond2)
{
    ...
}
```

If the conditions are tedious to write or too difficult to read, then encapsulate them in a method or evaluate them once and save them to a variable.

If you really really want to communicate why you did not handle a certain condition, write a comment above the method or the statement.

Comment: This is a much more appropriate answer.